# Capture PHP Errors from SMTP

Tags: php, smtp

I have the following code:

```
if($result = $this->Email->peopleFollowingEmail($follow['User']['email'], $viewer['User']['fname'].' '.$viewer['User']['lname'], $viewer['User']['username']))
{
    $pf_model->id = $id;
    $pf_model->saveField('sent_email', 1);
}
else
{
    $pf_model->id = $id;
    $pf_model->saveField('email_error', $result);
}
```

The `Email` function either will return `true` or return `$errMessage`.

How do I store the error message in my db?  I think my `$result = ...` is wrong.

Comment: What e-mail function? Any errors? Why do you think that is wrong? Please provide more information :) For example, we have no possibility to say if the code is wrong without knowing what `$pf_model` look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
$result = $this->Email->peopleFollowingEmail($follow['User']['email'], $viewer['User']['fname'].' '.$viewer['User']['lname'], $viewer['User']['username']);
if($result === true)
{
    $pf_model->id = $id;
    $pf_model->saveField('sent_email', 1);
}
else
{
    $pf_model->id = $id;
    $pf_model->saveField('email_error', $result);
}
```

Comment: Its the same as the OP code, other than "true" will not be treated as error.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by OP?

Comment: Original Poster, the one that posted the question

Comment: I think his problem is because the assignation inside the if condition is matched both if true or a string is returned... So i simply tried to assure that this doesn't happen

Comment: using this worked...i had some problems when i was using the other one as i was chaining the return $reults through 3 functions

Answer (score 0):

If it returns error message and it's a string you are doing it right. If its not a string you need to serialize it before passing it to database using `serialize($result)` and `unserialize($value)` when you want to read it back.